# Regular expression matching numbers

Tags: python, regex

```
>>> import re
>>> b = re.findall(r'^\d{,3}(,\d{3})*','12,344,567')
>>> b
[',567']
```

I hope to get ['12,344,567'],but the actual output is [',567'].Where is it wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parenthesis stores only the last match that was captured by it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `?:` or else the regex captures only what's within paranthesis:

```
^\d{,3}(?:,\d{3})*
```

**Example**:

```
import re

b = re.findall(r'^\d{,3}(?:,\d{3})*','12,344,567')
print(b)
# ['12,344,567']
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you might want to design an expression similar to:

```
import re

regex = r"^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$"
test_str = ("12,344,567")

print(re.findall(regex, test_str))
```

#### Output

```
['12,344,567']
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/o4Rwt2/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.